# Electron fs.writeFileSync in absolute path

Tags: angular, electron

This is my code:

```
  ipcMain.on('saveFile', async (event, path, fileName, data) => {

  fs.readFile(data, (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  fs.writeFileSync(path+fileName, data, 'binary');
});
```

});

I want to write in path like X:/Dir1/Dir2/ but my electron app thinks I want to write inside appdir AppDir/X:/Dir1/Dir2 and fails. Why? How can I achieve what I want. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply set path like X:\\Dir1\\Dir2\\

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).